# Giving Blessings at a Wedding

Tags: minhag, blessing, wedding

I have noticed a custom among wedding-goers to receive blessings from the bride and the groom at weddings, usually when they come over to the new couple's table for well-wishing during the meal. Why is this done specifically at weddings? I have never seen such a custom elsewhere.

Comment: You will notice the same behavior at a Brit Mila - especially by Sefardim and sometimes by Chassidim - where the Sandek does not get off his chair until he has given an individual Bracha to all those lined up for one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rabbi Chaim Fuchs Shlita](http://www.kikarhashabat.co.il/%D7%A1%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%AA%D7%9F-%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%94.html) writes as follows.

It is mentioned in the name of Radomsker Rabbi Zatzal that when he heard that the Tchetcheniv Rabbi Zatzal got sick, he said that the Arizal says that it says in the Zemiros of Friday night "LeOris V'Arusa L'Hitakfa Chalashin" indicates that at a wedding is an opportune time to effect for one that is ill.

Therefore the Minhag became to request a Bracha from the Chasan and Kallah to pray for those that are ill or single on the day of their wedding, when they are forgiven for their sins, and they are considered Tzadikim.

In addition the Bracha of a Chasan and kallah is effective for Parnasa when they bless together, since the words "חתן וכלה" equals the two names which are opportune for Parnasa "פא״י חת״ך" which are the beginning and ending letters of "פותח את ידיך" and "חת״ך" is also the ending letters of "והיית אך שמח" thus both because of the Simcha of the Chasan and Kallah + the Bracha of the Chasan and Kallah.

> זמן האירוסין מסוגל לרפואה, ומובא בשם הרב הקדוש מרדומסק כששמע שנחלה
>   הרה״ק מציעשונוב זי״ע שהרי כתוב בשם הארי ז"ל בזמירות ליל שבת ״לארוס
>   וארוסא להתקפא חלשין״. ועוד אמרו חז"ל פסחים סח עתידים צדיקים להחיות
>   מתים וזה יהיה באחרית הימים, ועכשיו אנו בזמן הארוסין.
>
> אמנם, הצדיקים יכולים אינם יכולים כיום להחיות מתים אך לרפא חולים הם
>   יכולים ומכאן השתרבב המנהג לבקש מהחתן והכלה המאורסים להתפלל על החולים
>   ועל הרווקים במיוחד ביום החתונה, כאשר נמחלים להם כל עוונותיהם והרי הם
>   בגדר צדיקים.
>
> ועוד סגולה לברכתם של החתן והכלה לפרנסה טובה אך רק כאשר הם מברכים יחדיו
>   שהרי גימטריה ״חתן וכלה״ עולים כמניין שני השמות הידועים לפרנסה - פא״י
>   חת״ך - שהם ראשי תיבות פותח את ידיך וגם סופי התיבות של והיית אך שמח,
>   כלומר, גם מצד של השמחה תבוא פרנסה וגם מצד הברכה של החתן והכלה.

Comment: Source from Pesachim if you care to add it:http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=pesachim&daf=68a&go=Go

Answer (score 2):

On their wedding night, God forgives the bride and groom for all their sins. Therefore, people go over to them to get a blessing, as you are getting a blessing from someone who has no sins (similar to someone going over to a Rabbi or Tzadik to ask for a blessing, and Tzadik Gozer V'Hakadosh Baruch Hu Mikayem (lit. A righteous man decrees and God fulfills)). Since the bride and groom (hopefully) have no sins yet (having just been forgiven), they fall under the category of Tzadik.

Similarly, the prayers of children are said to have the same effect, since children are pure and free of sin (until the age of Bar or Bat Mitzvah).

Unfortunately, I don't know the sources off the top of my head and I don't have the time to look it up. If I happen to remember where it is (or someone else points it out), I'll edit it in later.

Comment: thank you for this, looking forward to seeing sources when you have the time!

Comment: http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_81.html[ומאחר שחתן מוחלין לו על כל עוונותיו, לכן נהגו בכמה מקומות לבקש ברכה מהחתן, אך יש ליזהר שהדבר לא יגרום להפרעת השמחה של החתן והכלה]. [חופה וקידושין עמוד צ]

Comment: http://www.leageva.co.il/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3-%D7%A1%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%96%D7%95%D7%92%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%94/* סגולה נוספת למציאת זיווג הינה לשמח חתן וכלה , ועל הרווקה לבקש ברכה מהכלה , ועל הרווק לבקש ברכה מהחתן. טוב גם לשתות מהיין של החתן והכלה [מהקידוש]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect (but have no source for claiming) that it may be an application of one of these traditions, cited in *Nit'e Gavriel* (*Nisuin* volume 1):

- When the groom is beneath the wedding canopy is an *es ratzon*, time of willingness, when God grants his prayers. (Chapter 18, footnote 13.)
- It was customary that, during the wedding meal, the master of ceremonies would recite a "*mi sheberach*" prayer, asking for God's blessings upon all those present. (Chapter 39, paragraph 21.)